# How to use Jenkins parameterized builds?

Tags: java, ant, parameters, build, jenkins

Jenkins allows you to parameterize builds, but I can't figure out how to actually make use of it:

[image]

Say I would normally kick my Ant build off from the command-line like so:

```
ant -buildfile /path/to/my/build.xml -DpackageType=jar package
```

This would invoke the `build.xml`'s `package` target, and make a property named `packageType` available to it, with a value of `jar`.

I'm assuming that in the screenshot above, the **Name** field is where I would specify `packageType`, but what about the value?

1. If Jenkins wants me to specify a **Default Value** for the property, then where do I specify the value that my project is using? For instance, I might want a **Default Value** of `war`, but have this Jenkins job pass in a value of `jar` (to override the default).
2. Also, what does Jenkins mean by "...*allows the user to save typing the actual value.*" Which user? Where would you type the value anyways?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Whenever the user configures a parameterised build in Jenkins, the parameter name is taken as an environment variable

The user can make use of such parameters using the environment variable.

For example, in your case if **packageType** is the parameter you want to pass,

then specify the name as **packageType** and value as **war**

You can use it in the script you required as **`%packageType%`** (for Batch) or **`$packageType`** (for shell)

After configuring the job, whenever you click the build now button, Jenkins prompts for the parameter

When you are using file Parameter, the uploaded file will be placed into the working directory

Comment: Ahhhh that ties everything together for me: **Jenkins prompts you at buildtime**. Now it makes sense - thanks!

Comment: From Jenkins "Execute Shell," I was able to access a `String Parameter`'s value via `$FOOBAR` where `FOOBAR` is a build parameter. Using `%FOOBAR%` did not work for me.

Comment: %PARAM% is for batch and $PARAM is for shell