# Jenkins Paramterized Build TFS Labelling

Tags: maven, jenkins, tfs, build

I want to build a parametrized build which accept TFS label  in Jenkins , it is already pulling source code and building jars, however I want to give label on the fly and whenever required only . 
Curious if it is possible to give label in a dialog box when I kick off build in jenkins using GUI ?

If yes , how do we do that ?  Please note that I don't want to label every time and it is just of some of the time whenever we are releasing the code.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991273/how-to-use-jenkins-parameterized-builds

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer , you can parameterized it by checking the box "This build is parameterized" and once you give the param then you can pass it as $Label in post action to apply TFS label. 
When you click on the "Build now" , it will ask you to give the param value .