# How to make a job trigger for a specific range of repos but not ALL the repos?

Tags: jenkins, repository

Just wanted to know if you are able to make a job trigger for a specific range of repos but not ALL the repos ? If so what tool worked for you and how did you design? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get your query, but I am assuming you want Jenkins to be able to run jobs based on different/specific repositories. For this, you can make your Jenkins job as  Parametrized build. Consider looking into this-
[How to use Jenkins parameterized builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991273/how-to-use-jenkins-parameterized-builds)